# Boolean logic in function

Tags: python

This function compares the Instagram followers count of two accounts, and taking the input from the user (a guess as to which one has more followers). I created a longer version of if/elif statements but instructor wrote this shorter version:

```
def check_answer(guess, a_followers, b_followers):
    if a_followers > b_followers:
        return guess == 'a'
    else:
        return guess == 'b'
```

I am unable to understand why `return guess == 'a'`  returns a boolean value. I know that a double equal sign checks equality between two entities.

Comment: If guess equals "a", it returns True, otherwise it returns False

Comment: think about what `if a_followers > b_followers` means.

Comment: Try doing `print('a' == 'a')` and `print('a' == 'b')`.  Seeing how they act in a `print` might help you understand how they act in a `return`.  They do the exact same thing in both contexts.  You can also do `foo = 'a' == 'a'` and get the same result (`foo` will be a boolean value).

Comment: What do you *expect* this function to return, if not a boolean value? It would be easier to explain your confusion if you stated why the result does not match your expectation - that is, if you told us what you think this function should return.

Answer (score 1):

'guess' is a value passed in the function along with the a-folowers and b-followers parameters. When a-followers are greater than b-followers, if condition holds true and it compares whether the guess passed in as a parameters matches with the literal 'a'. When its true the expression returns True, otherwise False.

return statement evaluates to True or False, depending upon whether the two matches or not.

Answer (score 1):

`==` operator is used to check equality of two objects, and if two objects are equal then this operator returns boolean object `True`, if not - `False`:

```
>>> "string" == "string"
True
>>> "String 2" == "string 2"
False
```

In the case with `return`, python interpreter at first counts the result of the expression `guess == 'a'` and the return the given result. So if `guess` is equal to `'a'`, then function returns `True`, otherwise `False`.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is a comparison operator. I usually think of them as a function that takes the two values on either side of it, then returns either `True` or `False`. For example, `guess == 'a'` compares the value of `guess` to `'a'` and the returns `True` if they are the same and `False` if they are different. Other comparators are `>`, `<`, `!=`, and so on that check for different things.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not state what you think the function should return, but to understand why this function returns a boolean, we have to look at the return statements:

```
return guess == 'a'
```

`return` is a keyword in Python that has the form `return SOME_VALUE`, and will hand back to the calling function `SOME_VALUE`. Now, the value can be either a value (for instance, `return True`, in which case the value is `True`), or one might find an 'expression' - most easily defined as 'something that can be converted into a value'.

Because the interpreter finds an expression (in this case, `guess == 'a'`) after the `return` keyword, it decides to convert that expression into a value. We might see this same sort of expression in an `if` function:

```
if guess == 'a':
    print("Correct")
```

In both the `return` and `if` cases, the expression is 'evaluated' - converted to a value. In this case, `guess` is a variables - also an expression - so this is converted into values by 'dereferencing' it. Thus, if `guess` is equal to `b`, `guess == 'a'` is  converted to `'b' == 'a'`. This is still an expression, though, though one without any sub-expressions in it. As a result, a final evaluation is done.

The `==` sign is what is known as 'semantic sugar' for a function of the form:

```
is_equal(left, right) -> bool
```

This function will return `True` if the two parameters are equal, and `False` otherwise. This is all under the hood, but as we can see `b` and `a` are not equal, the function returns the value `False`. Thus, `'b' == 'a'` is evaluated to `False`, and the statement `return guess == 'a'` is evaluated in several steps to be equivalent to `return False`.

(Note that if `guess` was also `'a'` it would evaluate to `return True`.)

Almost everything you see will be this sort of series-of-evaluations as statements are evaluated into values. And that is why your function returns a boolean value - the only possible return values are `True` or `False`, both of which are booleans.

Answer (score 0):

### Operators

Python, like most languages (except lisp, *cough cough*), has something called infix operators (or simply operators).

These operators take **two arguments**, and returns a value.

The syntax is

```
argument1 <OPERATOR> argument2
```

For example, `+` is an operator, that can take two numbers, and return a number. Same for `*`

```py
>>> 2 + 1
3
>>> 5 * 2
10
```

At execution, the `argument1 <OPERATOR> argument2` is replaced by its value. For example, take the function `f`

```py
>>> def f(x):
   return x + 3
>>> f(4)
7  # x + 3 in the function has been replaced by the value of 4 + 3, which is 7
```

### Boolean Operators

Now the question is **What is** `==` **?**

#### Well `==` is just another operator.

But it is a so-called **boolean operator**, it doesn’t return numbers, but booleans

For example:

```py
>>> 3 == 2
False
>>> "hello" == "hello"
True
```

What does that mean for your function? Well the syntax `guess == 'a'` will be replaced by the value of `==` for the arguments `guess` and `a`. Which is

- `True` if the value of `guess` is `'a'`
- `False` otherwise